# Convert a string value to integer in c shell script

Tags: shell, csh

I need to convert a string value to integer in c shell. I am passing a string variable from Python to c shell script and in c shell in need to change it to integer. The variable I am passing is say br ="2" but in c shell in need to change it to integer 2.
Any solution that allows me to pass an integer value from python to c shell will also help.

```
import subprocess
import shlex

var = "nest"
env_var = "16"
script = "./testshell.csh"

#prepare a command (append variable to the scriptname)
command = "{} {}".format(script, var)
#prepare environment variables
environment = {"test_var" : env_var}

#Note: shlex.split splits a textual command into a list suited for subprocess.call
subprocess.call( shlex.split(command), env = environment )
```

This is the test shell script

```
#!/bin/csh

set br = $test_var
@ nvar = br + 1
echo $nvar
```

Error is: @: Expression Syntax.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just use it in the context of an integer. When testing, using the integer test; ie: <, ==, >, etc...

Comment: @user590028 I am not being able to use it as an integer.

Comment: I am not being able to use it as an integer

Comment: What is the `testshell` script doing? What error are you getting? Why are you creating the `command` string only to then split it back apart?

Comment: testshell.csh is using the variable for other purposeIt is using the variable value as an integer to perform other tasks in the shell script. updated the question

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you forgot to prefix `br` with a dollar sign (`$`), it should be:

```
@ nvar = $br + 1
```

Example:

```
% set br = '2'
% @ nvar = $br + 1
% echo $nvar
3
```